# VBA Decimal values

Tags: excel, vba

The below routine replace activecell  integer numbers with the number and = before the number and the number two columns to the right, but display error 1004 when the number is decimal.

How can I fix it???

```
    Sub EnterEqual()
     Dim CellContent As Variant
     Dim cell As Variant

    For Each cell In Selection
        CellContent = cell.Value
        cell.ClearContents
        cell.Value = "=" & CellContent & "+" & "rc[2]"
    Next cell


End Sub
```

Comment: Aren't you trying to result in an addition here? It's best if you can give us an indication of your input data and expected output here as a sample... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub EnterEqual()
     Dim CellContent As Integer '-- not sure why you need to use variant here
     Dim cell As Range '-- this has to be a range object

    For Each cell In Selection
        CellContent = cell.Value
        cell.ClearContents
        '-- you may add this as a formula
        cell.formula = "=" & CellContent & "+" & "RC[2]"
        '-- or use the below formular1c1
        cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & CellContent & " + " & "RC[2]"
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: It continuous to display error even if I change the cell.value to cell.formula.
The problem is that excel vba writes cell.value = "=2" BUT not cell.value = "=2,2"

Comment: Tested it out and it works in my end for adding up 2 and 0.2 or 2 and 0.02...etc.

Comment: what means <in my end>, how to amend the cell.value="=2,2"

Answer (score 0):

To update the cell formula you need to use one of the `.Formula` properties.  From your comment to bonCodigo, it seems your local number format uses `,` for decimal point, so use this

```
Sub EnterEqual()
     Dim CellContent As Variant
     Dim cell As Range  ' <=== change type

    For Each cell In Selection
        CellContent = cell.Value  ' This get the result of any existing formula as a value.  
        cell.ClearContents
        cell.FormulaR1C1Local = "=" & CellContent & "+" & "rc[2]"
    Next cell
End Sub
```